# why my active piezo buzzer doesn't give any signal as an input?

Tags: arduino, piezo-buzzer

I wanted to use my active buzzer as a vibration sensor like the knock lock project of the arduino starters and problem is I can't get any output out of it

I expected that that it is because the oscillator associated with the piezo element in the active buzzers but I couldn't figure out why and I couldn't find any topics talking about this issue either so if any one could explain why it's not giving any output on vibrating and a solution around this problem ( if any ) would be appreciated.

Link of the Datasheet:

https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/Buzzer%20Datasheet.pdf

Comment: What is "my active buzzer"? No part number, no link to datasheet, no photo, no answer.

Comment: @Transistor I thought that it's known that all the active buzzer are the same or something

Comment: No you need to be specific :)

Comment: @Jakob sorry post edited :D

Comment: There seems to some confusion.  There is a difference between a "passive" piezo element.and an "active" buzzer. What confuses everybody is that when you apply a voltage, within the limit specified in the datasheet, an "active" buzzer is formed.  An analogy is this: resistor, capacitors, inductors are "passive" elements. But if you design a circuit with such passive elements, and apply power, it becomes active (power is there). / to continue, ...

Comment: References: (1) "Active buzzer buzzer sound alarm module cable Raspberry Pi Arduino active active":
https://www.ebay.de/itm/Aktiver-Summer-Buzzer-Sound-Alarm-Modul-Kabel-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-aktiv-active/252713798041?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

(2) :Active Piezo Buzzer Makes Sound On Both Rpi GPIO Low and High Level Signal - Asked 1 year ago, Viewed 2k times":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97980/active-piezo-buzzer-makes-sound-on-both-rpi-gpio-low-and-high-level-signal. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I expected that that it is because the oscillator associated with the
> piezo element in the active buzzers*

If it has an internal oscillator then, the actual piezo element is so far-removed from the electrical terminals of the device that it cannot be used (in reverse) as an input device.

Comment: Is there anyway to manipulate it ?

Comment: Open it up and attach wires directly to the piezo element.